# MongoDB Aggregation : How to compare among array of objects in same document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

Below is my document. I want to compare the objects in array **SKUPromo** and get only those objects which have overlapping dates.

```
{
  "_id": "2531090",
  "SKUPromo": [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "startDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-01-05T06:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "endDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-02-07T05:59:59.000Z"
      },
      "promotionID": "6262",
      "skuId": "2531090"
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      "startDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-06-25T05:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "endDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-07-16T04:59:59.000Z"
      },
      "promotionID": "10146",
      "skuId": "2531090"
    },
    {
      "_id": "3",
      "startDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-06-25T05:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "endDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-07-02T04:59:59.000Z"
      },
      "promotionID": "8749",
      "skuId": "2531090"
    },
    {
      "_id": "4",
      "startDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-06-04T05:00:00.000Z"
      }
      "endDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-06-11T04:59:59.000Z"
      },
      "promotionID": "10024",
      "skuId": "2531090"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5",
      "startDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "endDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-01-07T05:59:59.000Z"
      },
      "promotionID": "6262",
      "skuId": "2531090"
    }
  ]
}
```

The output should have below data,

```
{
  "_id": "2531090",
  "SKUPromo": [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "startDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-01-05T06:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "endDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-02-07T05:59:59.000Z"
      },
      "promotionID": "9345",
      "skuId": "2531090"
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      "startDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-06-25T05:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "endDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-07-16T04:59:59.000Z"
      },
      "promotionID": "10146",
      "skuId": "2531090"
    },
    {
      "_id": "3",
      "startDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-06-25T05:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "endDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-07-02T04:59:59.000Z"
      },
      "promotionID": "8749",
      "skuId": "2531090"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5",
      "startDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "endDateTime": {
        "$date": "2023-01-07T05:59:59.000Z"
      },
      "promotionID": "6262",
      "skuId": "2531090"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: _"... get only those objects which have overlapping dates"_  Do you mean that if an object's time span overlaps any other's time span, then it should be retained?  Or do you mean only return objects that have mutually overlapping time spans?

Comment: If an object's time span overlaps any other's time span. For example, obje 5's enddate is after obj 1's start date. Similarly obj 3's end date is after object 2's start date

Comment: The end date of one object should not be between another's start and end date

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what the OP is looking for but the challenge of iterating over a list and examining each element in the context of *the rest of the list* is a good one.  Here's a potential solution:

```js
//  The end date of one object should not be between another's start and end date – 

c = db.foo.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
    SKUPromo: {
        /*
          This is the pseudocode in regular javascript:
          len = SKUPromo.length;
          for(n = 0; n < len; n++) {
            targ = SKUPromo[n]
            for(m = 0; m < len; m++) {
              if(n == m) {  continue }
              if(targ.enddate < SKUPromo[m].enddate and targ.enddate > SKUPromo[m].startdate
                    idmap[targ._id].append(m);
              }
            }
          }
        */

        // Iterate over SKUPromo and call each one 'targ':
        $map: {input: "$SKUPromo", as: "targ", in: {

        // Now run a reduce over SKUPromo to assess against 'targ'.
        // The $mergeObjects is there to add the overlaps field
        // to the existing 'targ'.  In pipeline logic we cannot say:
        //    targ['overlaps'] = some_list
        // instead we must say:
        //    $mergeObjects: [ '$$targ', {overlaps: some_list}]
        //
        
              $mergeObjects: ["$$targ",
                {overlaps: {
                  $reduce: {input: "$SKUPromo",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        { // IF
                          $and: [
                            { $ne: ["$$targ", "$$this"] },
                            { $lt: ["$$targ.endDateTime", "$$this.endDateTime"] },
                            { $gt: ["$$targ.endDateTime", "$$this.startDateTime"] }
                          ]
                        },
                        { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this._id"]] }, // THEN
                        "$$value" // ELSE
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
    // Only keep things with anything in the overlaps array:
    ,{$project: {
      overlaps: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$SKUPromo",
          as: "targ",
          cond: { $ne: ["$$targ.overlaps", []] }
        }
      }
    }
  }

]);
```

This yields:

```
{
  _id: '2531090',
  overlaps: [
    {
      _id: '3',
      startDateTime: ISODate("2023-06-25T05:00:00.000Z"),
      endDateTime: ISODate("2023-07-02T04:59:59.000Z"),
      promotionID: '8749',
      skuId: '2531090',
      overlaps: [
        '2'
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: '5',
      startDateTime: ISODate("2023-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"),
      endDateTime: ISODate("2023-01-07T05:59:59.000Z"),
      promotionID: '6262',
      skuId: '2531090',
      overlaps: [
        '1'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it using `"$reduce"`.  Comments are in the aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      // rewrite SKUPromo
      "SKUPromo": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$SKUPromo",
          // start with empty array
          // consider each element in turn
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "thisSKUP": "$$this"
              },
              "in": {
                "$cond": [
                  { // does thisSKUP have any overlap
                    // with any other array element
                    "$reduce": {
                      "input": "$SKUPromo",
                      "initialValue": false,
                      "in": {
                        "$or": [
                          "$$value",
                          {
                            "$and": [
                              { // don't consider overlap with self
                                "$ne": ["$$this._id", "$$thisSKUP._id"]
                              },
                              // 2 conditions of overlap
                              {
                                "$lte": ["$$thisSKUP.startDateTime", "$$this.endDateTime"]
                              },
                              {
                                "$gte": ["$$thisSKUP.endDateTime", "$$this.startDateTime"]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  { // overlap exists, add element
                    "$concatArrays": ["$$value", ["$$this"]]
                  },
                  // no overlap, just keep current array
                  "$$value"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VtagG_CdrMI).